# Unable to appy background panel image dynamically for chrome in Extjs

Tags: css, dom, extjs, extjs4, sencha-architect

I have a desktop like application with a panel as a base and it has a background. I have a form with multiple images to change the panel background dynamically. I have used below code to work for both Firefox and IE. But none is working for Chrome. But I came to know that it is better to directly apply to panel div element.

The code i used is:

```
panelbg.setBodyStyle({
backgroundImage: 'url('+bgimage+') !important',
backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
backgroundPosition: 'center',
backgroundSize: 'contain'
});

panelbg.setBodyStyle('background-image','url('+bgimage+')');    
panelbg.setBodyStyle('backgorund=position','center');
panelbg.setBodyStyle('background-size','cover');
```

How do I simply set panel background without having to use multiple statements?

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: I tried with the following too..Ext.fly('mainViewPanel').el.setStyle({
        backgroundImage:'url('+bgimage+') !important',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    });

Comment: Ext.fly('myPanel').el.dom.setStyle({
backgroundImage:url('+wallpaper+')';
}); I think this has to work but it saying that there is "null" value present.

Comment: make sure the path to the image is referenced correctly and that the element you are trying to add the background image to exists or is selected correctly

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried concatenating functions:

```
panelbg.setBodyStyle('background-image','url('+bgimage+')').setBodyStyle('backgorund=position','center').setBodyStyle('background-size','cover');
```

Comment: It is only working for Firefox but not IE & Chrome. I am mainly concerned about Chrome. Chrome supports HTML5 more than any other browser and my app will run better. But this thing only stopping me to move forward. Is there any chance to get the Div of the panel update it...?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried (*pay attention to brackets, semicolons and nesting quotes*):

```
panelbg.setBodyStyle({
    "backgroundImage: url(bgimage) !important;
     backgroundRepeat: no-repeat;
     backgorundPosition: center;
     backgroundSize: contain;"
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers.. Actually initially there is a image set as background in config. So while applying "setBodyStyle" method it is not overriding. I have overridden the config and set the background image. Thank You All :)